# Lazy compose Observables

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming

Say I have this

```
Observable<A> getA() {
  return Observable.just(new A());
}

Observable<C> getC() {
  // ... some expensive call
  return Observable.just(new C());
}

Observable<B> getB() {
  return getA()
    .map(a -> {
      if (a.someCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setSomeFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      if (a.otherCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setOtherFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      final B b = new B(...);
      b.setC(getC().toBlocking().single());
      return b;
    });
}
```

where `getC()` does some expensive call (or has side-effects). I want to make this call and initialize `B.c` field only if `a.someCondition()` or `a. otherCondition()` are not met, as above.

How would I rewrite to get rid of `.toBlocking()`?

One way I thought about was to zip `getA()` and `getC()`:

```
Observable<B> getB() {
  return Observable.zip(getA(), getC(), (a, c) -> Tuple.of(a, c))
    .map(tuple -> {
      final A a = tuple._1;
      final C c = tuple._2;
      if (a.someCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setSomeFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      if (a.otherCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setOtherFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      final B b = new B(...);
      b.setC(c);
      return b;
    });
}
```

but this would make the expensive call all the time. Also makes it difficult to read where there are more complex conditions or when I have more than 2 Observables to zip.

**EDIT**:

@ESala's answer below works, but sometimes switch from `map` to `flatMap` would require a lot of changes. Does the solution below also work?

```
Observable<B> getB() {
  return getA()
    .map(a -> {
      if (a.someCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setSomeFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      if (a.otherCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setOtherFields(...);
        return b;
      }
      final B b = new B(...);
      getC().forEach(c -> b.setC(c));
      return b;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `flatMap` instead of a `map`, this way you avoid the `toBlocking` and the expensive call is only done when necessary.

Example:

```
Observable<B> getB() {
  return getA()
    .flatMap(a -> {                  // <-- flatMap here
      if (a.someCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setSomeFields(...);
        return Observable.just(b);   // <-- wrap in observable
      }
      if (a.otherCondition()) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.setOtherFields(...);
        return Observable.just(b);   // <-- wrap in observable
      }
      return getC().map(c -> {       // <-- expensive call executed
          B b = new B(...);          //     only when necessary
          b.setC(c);
          return b;
      });
    });
}
```

---

**Update** regarding the edit in the question:

I don't think switching to a `flatMap` would require a lot of changes. Do you have a concrete example?

About the alternative solution in your edit: it *could* work in this case, but I do not recommend it.

By doing this, you are creating another subscription, which is not managed by the main observable flow, and in general this should not happen. The `forEach` operator returns a `Disposable` which is left there hanging!

Some problems it can cause include: 1) if you unsubscribe the main observable, the `forEach` subscription would continue anyways, 2) if you specified a scheduler in the `getC()` method, the main observable could complete before the `forEach` had finished.

Comment: @tuxx no problem, I updated the answer to respond to the edit :)

Comment: I see that forEach returns void: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#forEach-rx.functions.Action1-

Comment: @tuxx oh, sorry about that, you are using RxJava1, I was talking about RxJava2 (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#forEach-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-). Anyways, its behavior is the same: the `forEach` operator creates another subscription which is not managed by the main flow and is not meant to be used this way.